# Python DB2 - Symbol not found

Tags: python, db2

After updating to Mac Catalina (version 10.15.6), I had to re-install Python and all dependent modules.
My problem now is that when adding the module ibm_db, I get the following error message when trying to run my program:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
```

I am using PyCharm 2018.3.7 (CE).

Anyone that has seen this, and have a fix for this?

Comment: You may also ask here by opening an issue: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb The Db2 driver installs libraries. Have you updated them? Best is to uninstall the Db2 driver and reinstall as part of the Python module.

Comment: Additionally, please try using python ibm_db at the bash shall (i.e. not using PyCharm  temporarily), to see if the symptom differs. When you re-installed the ibm_db module, did it recompile ibm_db.c from source-code (as distinct from using a pre-built binary)?

Comment: I have tried to run my Python program from the bash shell, and I get exactly the same error message. I did install the module from the PyCharm package manager, but as far as I know it basically installs using pip3 install.

Comment: Are other versions of python installed? Symptom looks like mismatch between the gcc compilation-environment versus execution-environment.

Comment: I have Python 2.7, 3.7 and 3.8 installed.

Comment: Are these different versions of python in virtual environments? Possible breakdown of isolation between the different versions, resulting in wrong version of libraries being loaded. Are any of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_VERSIONED_LIBRARY_PATH variables set by Pycharm when running a python version?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to older version of /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib installed in your system. New installation of ibm_db is looking for newer version of libstdc++.6.dylib.

There are two quick solution for it. You can use either one:

1. Install new gcc of version >= 8 in your system and set environment variable to use it so that libstdc++.6.dylib from new version of gcc should get picked up instead of existing old one.

OR,

2. export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clidriver/lib

Thanks.

Comment: For approach #1, which environment variable do you think we need set? could you kindly  write down the exactly name?