# Connect to IBM DB2 database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to connect to a cloud based IBM DB2 database using SQLAlchemy. Using the base ibm_db python library this works :

```
connection_string = 'DRIVER={DB2};DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=host.databases.appdomain.cloud;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=user;PWD=pass;SECURITY=SSL;'
conn = ibm_db.connect(connection_string, '', '')
```

However, trying to do the same using SQLAlchemy, the connect part just hangs/timeouts

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import ibm_db_sa

user = "user"
password = "pass"
host = "host.databases.appdomain.cloud"
port = "port"
database = "BLUDB"

db2_connection_string = (
    f'db2+ibm_db://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'
    ':SECURITY=SSL'
)

engine = create_engine(db2_connection_string)
connection = engine.connect() # timeouts here
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: have you seen this documentation on ibm:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0060891.htm

Comment: Code in the docu doesnt work, fails on the imports "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_db_sa.ibm_db_sa'"

Comment: Had you installed the required modules?

Comment: yes ibm_db and ibm_db_sa is intstalled

Answer (score 0):

Only use a connection string like this:

```
db2_connection_string = (
    f'db2://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'
    ':SECURITY=SSL;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;'
)
```

In this [line of code in ghstats.ps](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/blob/master/backend/ghstats.py#L106) is a working sample. The code is from this [IBM Cloud solution tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-serverless-github-traffic-analytics) which has a Python app with SQLAlchemy connecting to Db2 on Cloud.

As alternative, you can also try **ibm_db_sa** as driver prefix instead of **db2**. Make sure to import the right modules (ibm_db, ibm_db_sa).

Comment: Hello, none of this works -  same timeout issue

Comment: Are you using the correct port? Any firewalls in the middle?

Comment: yes, as I mentioned, it works using ibm_db library, doesn't using SQLAlchemy

Comment: And you added the PROTOCOL=TCPIP to the connection string?

Comment: yes..............

Comment: can you post your exact connection strings for both the "regular" connect and the one with SQLAlchemy? Replace the confidential stuff, but include all parameters

Answer (score 0):

You may find all information on how to use the driver here:

https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb

Ensure that you have `ibm_db` AND `ibm_db_sa` packages installed using conda or pip.

If you are using Python 3.7 you'll probably find this problem [Python DB2 - Symbol not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345819/python-db2-symbol-not-found/63418563#63418563)

Regards.